# How to remove part of string in php?

Tags: php

I have this string

```
NOTEBOOK > ABC
TABLET > DFG
```

I want to remove everything after '>' including '>'

I tried this

```
$category = substr($categoryGet,0,strrpos($categoryGet.">",">"));
```

No result so far

Comment: explode on line break, then explode on ">"

Comment: Why are you concatenating `">"` to the string? It will always find the character that you're adding, instead of the one that was in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`

```
$category = preg_replace('/>[^>]*$/m', '', $category);
```

The regular expression matches `>` followed by any non-`>` characters until the end of the line. The `m` modifier makes `$` match the end of each line in the string.

Comment: not sure if "NOTEBOOK > ABC TABLET" is what he wanted returned

Comment: No. nogad, 'NOTEBOOK'
'TABLET' this is what I wanted

Comment: @nogad I modified it to work by line using the `m` modifier.

Comment: @nogad I first thought they were separate strings, not one string with a newline.

Comment: a fair interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="NOTEBOOK > ABC
TABLET > DFG";

$x=explode("\n",$str); //break by lines

foreach($x as $y){
$k=explode('>',$y);

echo trim($k[0]); //or that ever form you want the output to be
}
```